# eclipse CDT create remote project

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse CDT to create a project on a Debian 7 with RDT up and running. My Eclipse is connected and I can browse the remote filesystem, etc.

According to eclipse's documentation, I can click on "File->New->Remote C++ Project"... BUT that opetion is not available!

Eclipse is:
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

```
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600
```

Running on Mac OSX with Java 1.7

Anyone knows what could be wrong?

Thanks!